# Реализация методов System.Object

Tags: c#

Задался вопросом, а где можно найти механизм методов System.Object? Ведь все время мы только используем или перегружаем эти методы, а где можно найти именно мехазм того же Equals()?
[image: F12]

VS к сожалению через "Показать определение" дает только описание методов.
Заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не вижу исходник пропустив библиотеку mscorlib.dll через ILdasm

Comment: Можно [посмотреть исходники](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,d9262ceecc1719ab)

Comment: @Grundy Не подскажите, в среде разработки где можно увидеть исходники?

Comment: В среде разработки - нигде. Максимум можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь декомпилятором, но это обычно и не нужно, особенно когда они есть в свободном доступе

Comment: @Grundy не хочу разводить дискусию, но не понимаю, почему скрыты тела методов, а лишь их описания. Так или иначе, спасибо ссылку на сорсы.

Comment: Тела не скрыты - просто у тебя на машине нет _исходников_, на которые могла бы перейти IDE.

Comment: @Grundy, а не подскажите как их загрузить?

Comment: @Yaroslav, неа, можно посмотреть в сторону [dotnet core](https://github.com/dotnet)

Comment: @Grundy странно, нет исходников, но есть механизм реализации и перекрытия? Все сорсы на namespace System хранятся в mscorlib.dll.

Comment: @Rifter, не надо путать исходный код, и скомпилированную библиотеку.

Comment: @Grundy, интересно было за .NET Framework

Comment: @Grundy даже пропустив через дизасемблер так и не увидел тела метода, добавил скрин в вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не увидите реализации `Object.Equals` в .NET коде. Вызов этого метода в .NET вызывает нативный код. Вы можете посмотреть исходник этого метода в исходниках `clr`: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/objectnative.cpp#L153

```
//
// Compare by ref for normal classes, by value for value types.
//  
// <TODO>@todo: it would be nice to customize this method based on the
// defining class rather than doing a runtime check whether it is
// a value type.</TODO>
//

FCIMPL2(FC_BOOL_RET, ObjectNative::Equals, Object *pThisRef, Object *pCompareRef)
{
    CONTRACTL
    {
        FCALL_CHECK;
        INJECT_FAULT(FCThrow(kOutOfMemoryException););
    }
    CONTRACTL_END;

    if (pThisRef == pCompareRef)    
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(TRUE);

    // Since we are in FCALL, we must handle NULL specially.
    if (pThisRef == NULL || pCompareRef == NULL)
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(FALSE);

    MethodTable *pThisMT = pThisRef->GetMethodTable();

    // If it's not a value class, don't compare by value
    if (!pThisMT->IsValueType())
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(FALSE);

    // Make sure they are the same type.
    if (pThisMT != pCompareRef->GetMethodTable())
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(FALSE);

    // Compare the contents (size - vtable - sync block index).
    DWORD dwBaseSize = pThisRef->GetMethodTable()->GetBaseSize();
    if(pThisRef->GetMethodTable() == g_pStringClass)
        dwBaseSize -= sizeof(WCHAR);
    BOOL ret = memcmp(
        (void *) (pThisRef+1), 
        (void *) (pCompareRef+1), 
        dwBaseSize - sizeof(Object) - sizeof(int)) == 0;

    FC_GC_POLL_RET();

    FC_RETURN_BOOL(ret);
}
FCIMPLEND
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я видимо не понимаю всего механизма компиляции. Как я себе представляю - После запуска компилятора C# превращается в IL модули с метаданными, которые собираются в сборки и далее компилируются в нативные функции. На каком этапе код C++ смешивается с C#? И как IntelSense тогда воспринимает синтаксис C# с библиотеками написанными на другом языке?

Comment: @Rifter IL cборки компилируются в нативные при помощи CLR, который написан на С++. CLR может на свое усмотрение на место вызова .NET метода подставлять какой-то нативный, который находится внутри CLR.